# Clean install of QGIS version 2.18.27 from OSGEO4W Network Installer fails

Tags: qgis-2.18, osgeo4w

I simply cannot get a clean install of QGIS version 2.18.27. I seem unable to access any working SAGA tools. **I used to have access to these tools in version 2.18.23, Standalone Installer**
The Log Errors are:

```
2018-12-27T09:59:39 1   warning:C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py:844: PendingDeprecationWarning: This method will be removed in future versions.  Use 'elem.iter()' or 'list(elem.iter())' instead.
          for include in elem.getiterator("include"):

        traceback:  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 333, in startPlugin
            plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
          File "C:/Users/Bing/.qgis2/python/plugins\LeastCostPath\__init__.py", line 34, in classFactory
            from .LeastCostPath import LeastCostPath
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:/Users/Bing/.qgis2/python/plugins\LeastCostPath\LeastCostPath.py", line 28, in <module>
            from LeastCostPath_dialog import LeastCostPathDialog
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:/Users/Bing/.qgis2/python/plugins\LeastCostPath\LeastCostPath_dialog.py", line 29, in <module>
            os.path.dirname(__file__), 'LeastCostPath_dialog_base.ui'))
          File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\__init__.py", line 210, in loadUiType
            winfo = compiler.UICompiler().compileUi(uifile, code_string, from_imports, resource_suffix)
          File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\Compiler\compiler.py", line 139, in compileUi
            w = self.parse(input_stream, resource_suffix)
          File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 933, in parse
            actor(elem)
          File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 844, in readResources
            for include in elem.getiterator("include"):

2018-12-27T09:59:39 1   warning:C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py:113: DeprecationWarning: gdalconst.py was placed in a namespace, it is now available as osgeo.gdalconst
          DeprecationWarning)

        traceback:  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 333, in startPlugin
            plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
          File "C:/Users/Bing/.qgis2/python/plugins\LeastCostPath\__init__.py", line 34, in classFactory
            from .LeastCostPath import LeastCostPath
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:/Users/Bing/.qgis2/python/plugins\LeastCostPath\LeastCostPath.py", line 36, in <module>
            from gdalconst import *
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\gdalconst.py", line 3, in <module>
            deprecation_warn('gdalconst')  

2018-12-27T09:59:41 1   warning:C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py:607: ImportWarning: Not importing directory 'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\test': missing __init__.py
          mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)

        traceback:  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 333, in startPlugin
            plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
          File "C:/Users/Bing/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2web\__init__.py", line 28, in classFactory
            from .qgis2web import Qgis2Web
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:/Users/Bing/.qgis2/python/plugins\qgis2web\qgis2web.py", line 25, in <module>
            from processing.core.Processing import Processing
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
            from processing.tools.general import *              # NOQA
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 31, in <module>
            from processing.core.Processing import Processing
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 62, in <module>
            from processing.algs.saga.SagaAlgorithmProvider import SagaAlgorithmProvider
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\saga\SagaAlgorithmProvider.py", line 33, in <module>
            from SagaAlgorithm import SagaAlgorithm
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\saga\SagaAlgorithm.py", line 20, in <module>
            standard_library.install_aliases()
          File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\future\standard_library\__init__.py", line 483, in install_aliases
            import test

2018-12-27T09:59:43 1   warning:C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:858: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
          InsecureRequestWarning)

        traceback:  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 342, in startPlugin
            plugins[packageName].initGui()
          File "C:/Users/Bing/.qgis2/python/plugins\quick_map_services\quick_map_services.py", line 121, in initGui
            self.init_server_panel()
          File "C:/Users/Bing/.qgis2/python/plugins\quick_map_services\quick_map_services.py", line 311, in init_server_panel
            self.server_toolbox = QmsServiceToolbox(self.iface)
          File "C:/Users/Bing/.qgis2/python/plugins\quick_map_services\qms_service_toolbox.py", line 155, in __init__
            self.show_news()
          File "C:/Users/Bing/.qgis2/python/plugins\quick_map_services\qms_service_toolbox.py", line 160, in show_news
            qms_news = client.get_news()
          File "C:/Users/Bing/.qgis2/python/plugins\quick_map_services\qms_external_api_python\api\api_abstract.py", line 64, in get_news
            response = get(url, verify=False)
          File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 72, in get
            return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
          File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
            return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
          File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 508, in request
            resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
          File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 618, in send
            r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
          File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 440, in send
            timeout=timeout
          File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
            chunked=chunked)
          File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
            self._validate_conn(conn)

2018-12-27T09:59:44 1   warning:C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\pkgutil.py:186: ImportWarning: Not importing directory 'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits': missing __init__.py
          file, filename, etc = imp.find_module(subname, path)

        traceback:  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 333, in startPlugin
            plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\MetaSearch\__init__.py", line 29, in classFactory
            from MetaSearch.plugin import MetaSearchPlugin
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\MetaSearch\plugin.py", line 33, in <module>
            from MetaSearch.dialogs.maindialog import MetaSearchDialog
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\MetaSearch\dialogs\maindialog.py", line 48, in <module>
            from MetaSearch.dialogs.manageconnectionsdialog import ManageConnectionsDialog
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\MetaSearch\dialogs\manageconnectionsdialog.py", line 35, in <module>
            from MetaSearch.util import (get_connections_from_file, get_ui_class,
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\MetaSearch\util.py", line 41, in <module>
            from pygments.lexers import XmlLexer
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygments\lexers\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
            from pygments.plugin import find_plugin_lexers
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygments\plugin.py", line 39, in <module>
            import pkg_resources
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3017, in <module>
            @_call_aside
          File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3003, in _call_aside
            f(*args, **kwargs)
          File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3045, in _initialize_master_working_set
            dist.activate(replace=False)
          File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2577, in activate
            declare_namespace(pkg)
          File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2151, in declare_namespace
            _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
          File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2075, in _handle_ns
            loader = importer.find_module(packageName)

2018-12-27T09:59:44 1   warning:C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\pkgutil.py:186: ImportWarning: Not importing directory 'c:\osgeo4w64\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits': missing __init__.py
          file, filename, etc = imp.find_module(subname, path)

        traceback:  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 333, in startPlugin
            plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\MetaSearch\__init__.py", line 29, in classFactory
            from MetaSearch.plugin import MetaSearchPlugin
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\MetaSearch\plugin.py", line 33, in <module>
            from MetaSearch.dialogs.maindialog import MetaSearchDialog
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\MetaSearch\dialogs\maindialog.py", line 48, in <module>
            from MetaSearch.dialogs.manageconnectionsdialog import ManageConnectionsDialog
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\MetaSearch\dialogs\manageconnectionsdialog.py", line 35, in <module>
            from MetaSearch.util import (get_connections_from_file, get_ui_class,
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\MetaSearch\util.py", line 41, in <module>
            from pygments.lexers import XmlLexer
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygments\lexers\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
            from pygments.plugin import find_plugin_lexers
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygments\plugin.py", line 39, in <module>
            import pkg_resources
          File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3017, in <module>
            @_call_aside
          File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3003, in _call_aside
            f(*args, **kwargs)
          File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3045, in _initialize_master_working_set
            dist.activate(replace=False)
          File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2574, in activate
            fixup_namespace_packages(self.location)
          File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2162, in fixup_namespace_packages
            subpath = _handle_ns(package, path_item)
          File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2075, in _handle_ns
            loader = importer.find_module(packageName)
```

I also get the following when my the SAGA tool fails 'least cost path'.

```
2018-12-27T20:42:36 0   SAGA execution commands
        io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM 1 -RESAMPLING 3 -GRIDS "C:\Users\Bing\AppData\Local\Temp\processing339f196d424c47638cfae48af3937d1e\b09bc61840114a81b417442a4e370937\Cumulativecost.sgrd" -FILES "F:/QGIS/218/cumulative-costs.tif"
        grid_analysis "Least Cost Paths"  -SOURCE "F:/QGIS/218/end-and-start.shp" -DEM "C:\Users\Bing\AppData\Local\Temp\processing339f196d424c47638cfae48af3937d1e\b09bc61840114a81b417442a4e370937\Cumulativecost.sgrd" -POINTS "C:\Users\Bing\AppData\Local\Temp\processing339f196d424c47638cfae48af3937d1e\8b5e1bebd2fe44f9a702e80ac79adf48\POINTS.shp" -LINE "C:\Users\Bing\AppData\Local\Temp\processing339f196d424c47638cfae48af3937d1e\69f9cc2d152941bda2efcb1f23859604\LINE.shp"
2018-12-27T20:42:58 0   SAGA execution console output

        C:\OSGeo4W64\bin>set SAGA=C:/OSGeo4W64/apps\saga-ltr

        C:\OSGeo4W64\bin>set SAGA_MLB=C:/OSGeo4W64/apps\saga-ltr\modules

        C:\OSGeo4W64\bin>PATH=C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\shapely\DLLs;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\DLLs;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-ltr\bin;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\Scripts;C:\OSGeo4W64\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WBem;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\msys\bin;C:/OSGeo4W64/apps\saga-ltr;C:/OSGeo4W64/apps\saga-ltr\modules

        C:\OSGeo4W64\bin>saga_cmd io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM 1 -RESAMPLING 3 -GRIDS "C:\Users\Bing\AppData\Local\Temp\processing339f196d424c47638cfae48af3937d1e\b09bc61840114a81b417442a4e370937\Cumulativecost.sgrd" -FILES "F:/QGIS/218/cumulative-costs.tif"
        Error: select a library
        ____________________________

        #####   ##   #####    ##
        ###     ###  ##       ###
        ###   # ## ##  #### # ##
        ### ##### ##    # #####
        ##### #   ##  ##### #   ##
        ____________________________

        SAGA Version: 2.3.2 (64 bit)


        68 loaded tool libraries (630 tools):
        - climate_tools
        - contrib_perego
        - db_odbc
        - db_pgsql
        - docs_html
        - garden_3d_viewer
        - garden_fractals
        - garden_games
        - garden_learn_to_program
        - garden_webservices
        - grid_analysis
        - grid_calculus
        - grid_calculus_bsl
        - grid_filter
        - grid_gridding
        - grid_spline
        - grid_tools
        - grid_visualisation
        - imagery_classification
        - imagery_isocluster
        - imagery_maxent
        - imagery_photogrammetry
        - imagery_segmentation
        - imagery_svm
        - imagery_tools
        - io_esri_e00
        - io_gps
        - io_grid
        - io_grid_image
        - io_shapes
        - io_shapes_dxf
        - io_table
        - io_virtual
        - pj_georeference
        - pj_geotrans
        - pj_proj4
        - pointcloud_tools
        - pointcloud_viewer
        - shapes_grid
        - shapes_lines
        - shapes_points
        - shapes_polygons
        - shapes_tools
        - shapes_transect
        - sim_cellular_automata
        - sim_ecosystems_hugget
        - sim_erosion
        - sim_fire_spreading
        - sim_hydrology
        - sim_ihacres
        - sim_qm_of_esp
        - sim_rivflow
        - statistics_grid
        - statistics_kriging
        - statistics_points
        - statistics_regression
        - ta_channels
        - ta_compound
        - ta_hydrology
        - ta_lighting
        - ta_morphometry
        - ta_preprocessor
        - ta_profiles
        - ta_slope_stability
        - table_calculus
        - table_tools
        - tin_tools
        - tin_viewer

        type -h or --help for further information


        C:\OSGeo4W64\bin>saga_cmd grid_analysis "Least Cost Paths"  -SOURCE "F:/QGIS/218/end-and-start.shp" -DEM "C:\Users\Bing\AppData\Local\Temp\processing339f196d424c47638cfae48af3937d1e\b09bc61840114a81b417442a4e370937\Cumulativecost.sgrd" -POINTS "C:\Users\Bing\AppData\Local\Temp\processing339f196d424c47638cfae48af3937d1e\8b5e1bebd2fe44f9a702e80ac79adf48\POINTS.shp" -LINE "C:\Users\Bing\AppData\Local\Temp\processing339f196d424c47638cfae48af3937d1e\69f9cc2d152941bda2efcb1f23859604\LINE.shp"
        Error: input file [C:\Users\Bing\AppData\Local\Temp\processing339f196d424c47638cfae48af3937d1e\b09bc61840114a81b417442a4e370937\Cumulativecost.sgrd]
        Error: Accumulated Cost Surface
        ____________________________

        #####   ##   #####    ##
        ###     ###  ##       ###
        ###   # ## ##  #### # ##
        ### ##### ##    # #####
        ##### #   ##  ##### #   ##
        ____________________________

        SAGA Version: 2.3.2 (64 bit)

        ____________________________
        library path: C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\saga-ltr\modules\
        library name: grid_analysis
        library     : Analysis
        tool        : Least Cost Paths
        author      : O. Conrad, V. Olaya, V. Wichmann (c) 2004-2010
        processors  : 2 [2]
        ____________________________

        Load shapes: F:/QGIS/218/end-and-start.shp...


        Load grid: C:\Users\Bing\AppData\Local\Temp\processing339f196d424c47638cfae48af3937d1e\b09bc61840114a81b417442a4e370937\Cumulativecost.sgrd...
        failed

        Usage: saga_cmd grid_analysis 5 [-SOURCE <str>] [-DEM <str>] [-VALUES <str>] [-POINTS <str>] [-LINE <str>]
        -SOURCE:<str>   Source Point(s)
        Shapes (input)
        -DEM:<str>      Accumulated Cost Surface
        Grid (input)
        -VALUES:<str>   Values
        Grid list (optional input)
        -POINTS:<str>   Profile Points
        Shapes list (output)
        -LINE:<str>     Profile Lines
        Shapes list (output)

        C:\OSGeo4W64\bin>exit
```

Comment: These are just python warnings, and I get them too. What error message do you get?  Can you supply a sample dataset set should work? Maybe hub.qgis.org is a better place for your bug report.

Comment: I've been trying to run 'least cost path' tool - SAGA. But the same happens with any SAGA tool.  Data source is invalid () - is the error message @AndreJ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I gladly edit this answer.

**UPDATE:**

`gdal202dll` library was necessary for the operation of `saga_cmd io_gdal` commands from `saga-ltr`. The dependency was solved from OSGeo4W.

Run `C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\osgeo4w-setup.exe`, or the *Setup* direct access from the *OSGeo4W* group of Windows start menu.

Select *Advanced Setup* and follow. Select *Install from Internet* and follow.

Select your existing Root Directory and preferences until you reach the following screen:

[image: gdal202dll]

Check the global *Current* option that will automatically select the updates to the last stable versions of all the packages.
Make sure, in the *Pending* View, that the *gdal202dll* library package will be installed.
Proceed with the installation. **The SAGA tools will work again in QGIS**.

Keep in mind that SAGA tools are not prepared to read or write layers directly from or to the QGIS map canvas. As far as possible select the respective files instead of the loaded layers. Also, save the *Outputs* as files instead of loading as layers directly from temporary files.

---

<del>I don't know if QGIS should call `saga` instead of `saga-ltr`, or if there is an error in the code or compilation of `saga-ltr`, but it don't load the `io_gdal` library and render unusable several SAGA tools of QGIS in Windows. 

A [ticket](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ticket/589) was already opened. When the issue is resolved, I will gladly edit this answer.  


Meanwhile, the solution would be to run all the commands that the algorithm performs directly from *OSGEO4W Shell*, but changing the paths by `saga` instead of `saga-ltr`.  

Or better yet, [download the latest version of SAGA GIS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/saga-gis/files/) (7.1.1 to date) and perform the necessary tasks from there.  

Although I have read some criticisms, due to its lack of documentation and not fully optimized memory management, it seems to me an essential software. And it's *portable* for Windows, unzip it and run.  

I also share the link to their [website](http://www.saga-gis.org/en/index.html).</del>

Comment: Yes, please edit your answer once you have more detail @Gabriel De Luca. I need to find out how to " run all the commands that the algorithm performs directly from OSGEO4W Shell" - the learning curve for this software is steep! :-)

Comment: @IanGS, Issue was just solved from OSGeo4W. I edited my answer. In another question, if you want, you can ask How to reproduce at OSGeo4W Shell a SAGA algorithm? (verify that have not been asked before), copying a complete Log of a tool box like the second code of this question.